# laravel-excel library doesn't download doesn't output file to browser

Tags: excel, laravel, download, export-to-csv

I am using this laravel-excel library to export data to CSV file using query method like described here
https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/from-query.html

I have problems to output the CSV file to browser.
I've checked my export class and I couldn't find any error to break the code.

Here is my export class

```
namespace App\Exports;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromQuery;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithCustomCsvSettings;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadings;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithMapping;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\Cell;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\DataType;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\DefaultValueBinder;

class CanalAtendenteExport extends DefaultValueBinder 
    implements FromQuery, WithCustomCsvSettings, WithMapping, WithHeadings
{
    private $query;

    public function __construct(Builder $query)
    {
        $this->query = $query;
    }

    public function bindValue(Cell $cell, $value)
    {
        if (is_numeric($value)) {
            $cell->setValueExplicit($value, DataType::TYPE_STRING);

            return true;
        }

        return parent::bindValue($cell, $value);
    }
    
    public function query()
    {
        return $this->query;
    }
    
    public function getCsvSettings(): array
    {
        return [
            'delimiter' => ';', 'use_bom' => true
        ];
    }
    
    public function map($row): array
    {
        $array = [
            $row->atendente, $row->departamento
        ];

        return $array;
    }
    
    public function headings(): array
    {
        $array = [
            __('Atendente'), __('Departamento')
        ];

        return $array;
    }
}
```

The controller action  query to download the file is also working. No error is raised at this point.

```
public function exportarAtendentes($canalId, $format)
{
if (!isset($canalId)) {
$request->session()->flash('error', __('Cliente não informado.'));
return redirect()->back();
}
if (!isset($format)) {
$request->session()->flash('error', __('Formato inválido.'));
return redirect()->back();
}

$query = Canal::query()->join('canal_operador_departamentos','canals.id','=','canal_operador_departamentos.canal_id')->join('canal_departamentos','canal_departamentos.id','=','canal_operador_departamentos.departamento_id')->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'canal_operador_departamentos.user_id')->select('users.name as atendente','canal_departamentos.departamento as departamento')->where('canal_operador_departamentos.canal_id', '=', $canalId);
$filename = __('canal_atendentes') . ".{$format}";
return Excel::download(new CanalAtendenteExport($query), $filename);
}
```

The form controlls to call export function

```
<div class="dropdown d-inline">
<button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="buttonExpAtendentes" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
{{ __('Exportar') }}
</button>
<div class="dropdown-menu" x-placement="bottom-start">
<button name="ext" value="csv" class="dropdown-item has-icon exportar-atendente" data-url="{{ route('canais.atendentes.exportar', [ $instance->id, 'csv']) }}">
<i class="fas fa-file-csv"></i>CSV</button>
<button name="ext" value="xlsx" class="dropdown-item has-icon exportar-atendente" data-url="{{ route('canais.atendentes.exportar', [ $instance->id, 'xlsx']) }}">
<i class="fas fa-file-excel"></i>Excel</button>
</div>
</div>
```

I've checked output to browser console and no error is raised.